# How to access properties and methods of the non stable version of OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

How can I use objects, properties and methods of the OpenLayers 3 development version? For example, I want to use a property of ol.geom (ol.geom.translate) of the non stable version (3.4.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of OpenLayers that your webpage uses is based on whatever path you specify in the  tag.  So, just [download](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases) which ever version you want to use and save it in an appropriate location, then set your OpenLayers  tag to point to it.

**EDIT**
To get the very latest - on the download page, follow the link to the [GitHub code](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3) repository, where you can get the raw bleeding edge code.  You will need to build it yourself but this means you can customise the build to include only what you need (another advantage of OL3 vs OL2).

Comment: Thanks por responding, but the versions that are ready for download doens´t include some features that are in experimental mode in the OL3 API, only the stable ones. For example, ol.geom.translate ins not availabe in the stable versions.

Comment: You CAN get the "bleeding-edge" releases. See my edit above (for instance, at the time of writing, a quick glance showed the latest update was only 21 hours old).  The link you need is on the download page.

Comment: Now, your edit is exactly what I need. Thank you very much, MappaGnosis.